# Transform table from sequential identifier to real with attributes

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, powerbi

I changed a but the context, but it's basically the same issue.

Imagine we are in a never-ending tunnel, shaped like a circle. We split every section of the circle, from 1 to 10 and we'll call each section `slot (sl)`. There are 2 `groups (gr)` of living things walking in the tunnel. Each group has 2 `bands`, where each has a `name` and global `hitpoints (hp)`. Every group is walking forward (although the bands might change order). If a group is at slot #10 and moves forward, he will be at slot #1. We snapshot their information every `day`. All the data gathered is stored in a table with this structure:

```
+----------+----------------+------------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+--------------+--+
| day_id | | gr_1_sl_1_id | | gr_1_sl_1_name | | gr_1_sl_1_hp | | gr_1_sl_2_id | | gr_1_sl_2_name | | gr_1_sl_2_hp | | gr_2_sl_1_id | | gr_2_sl_1_name | | gr_2_sl_1_hp | | gr_2_sl_2_id | | gr_2_sl_2_name | | gr_2_sl_2_hp |  |
+----------+----------------+------------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+--------------+--+
|        1 |              3 | orc              |            100 |              4 | goblin           |             10 |             10 | human            |             50 |              1 | dwarf            |           25 |  |
|        2 |              6 | goblin           |              7 |              7 | orc              |             76 |              2 | human            |             60 |              3 | dwarf            |           28 |  |
+----------+----------------+------------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+--------------+--+
```

As you can see, the columns are structured in a sequential way, while the data shows what is the actual value. What I want is to have the information shaped this way instead:

```
+---------+-------+-------+-----------+---------+
| id_game | gr_id | sl_id | band_name | band_hp |
+---------+-------+-------+-----------+---------+
|       1 |     1 |     3 | orc       |     100 |
|       1 |     1 |     4 | goblin    |      10 |
|       1 |     2 |    10 | human     |      50 |
|       1 |     2 |     1 | dwarf     |      25 |
|       2 |     1 |     6 | goblin    |       7 |
|       2 |     1 |     7 | orc       |      76 |
|       2 |     2 |     2 | human     |      60 |
|       2 |     2 |     3 | dwarf     |      28 |
+---------+-------+-------+-----------+---------+
```

I have this information in power bi, although I can create views in sql server if need be. I have tried many things, closest thing I got was unpivoting and parsing the original columns to get `day_id`, `gr_id`, `sl_id`, `attributes` and `values`. In `attributes` and `values`, it's basically name and hp with their corresponding value (I changed hp into string), but then I'm stocked, I'm not sure what to do next.

Anyone has any ideas ? Keep in mind that I oversimplified the problem; there are more groups, more slots, more bands and more statistics (i.e. attack and defense rating, etc.)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to unpivot the table.  In SQL Server, I recommend using `apply`:

```
select t.day_id, v.*
form t cross apply
     (values (1, 1, gr_1_sl_1_id, gr_1_sl_1_name, gr_1_sl_1_hp),
             (1, 2, gr_1_sl_2_id, gr_1_sl_2_name, gr_1_sl_2_hp),
             (2, 1, gr_2_sl_1_id, gr_1_sl_1_name, gr_2_sl_1_hp),
             (2, 2, gr_2_sl_2_id, gr_1_sl_2_name, gr_2_sl_2_hp)
     ) v(id_game, gr_id, sl_id, band_name, band_hp);
```

In other databases, you can do something similar with `union all`.

Comment: It does work. Second time I hear cross apply and its magic effect. Thanks !